# How to resolve this error in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

I am building a Cordova Application in XCode, but I am getting the following error :-

```
CDVLocation.m 'Cordova/NSArray+Comparisons.h' file not found 


cordova platform
Installed platforms: android 5.1.1, ios 4.0.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, osx, webos


Mac-de-binov:icooltaxi binov$ cordova plugin
cl.rmd.cordova.dialoggps 0.0.2 "DialogGPS"
com.cordova.plugins.sms 0.1.9 "Cordova SMS Plugin"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
in.girish.datagram 0.1.0 "UDP Plugin"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please update your post with `cordova plugins` and `cordova platforms` commands output?

Comment: look please i edit it